# Webservicex giving wrong EUR:USD conversion

Tags: magento-1.9, currency, web-services

On our site our base currency is Euro and we have two display currencies, US Dollars & Pound Sterling.[image]

Today, I noticed that the US Dollar rate was the same as the Euro rate, 1:1. This is obviously wrong, todays rate on xe.com is 1:1.06.

We're using Magento 1.9.2.2 and webservicex to update the currency each night at midnight.
[image]

Up until today it has worked fine, I can even see from yesterdays orders that it was giving the correct rates. Today it is off, any idea why?

I've checked the historic rates and it has not gone bellow 1:1.06 in a while, I tried getting the exchange rates directly from [webservicex](http://www.webservicex.net/WS/WSDetails.aspx?WSID=10) but I can't really figure it out. Interestingly the Euro/Sterling rate seems fine!

**UPDATE**

I found that if I manually update the rates and save them, once I try to import them from webservicex, the new rate is the same as the old rate, which I just manually updated, no matter what number I put in!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because of an error on webservicex website. Check this link: http://www.webservicex.net/CurrencyConvertor.asmx/ConversionRate?FromCurrency=EUR&ToCurrency=USD It shows "-1" as response, seems like an error code. Maybe Magento does not handles this value correctly (as an error)

Answer (score 11):

There does seem to be an issue with the WebserviceX currency conversion service. I've knocked together an extension that integrates with the [fixer.io](http://fixer.io) service, which can act as an alternative: https://github.com/c3limited/FixerIOCurrencyImport

Comment: Thanks for putting up a fix for this! This worked on my CE1.9.0.1 site, including the cron job.

Comment: Will this work on Magento 1.7 version?